# SELECT only where relational row is found

Tags: sql, join

I have 2 tables like this in my database:

**menu_categories**

```
* id
* name
* description
```

**dishes**

```
* id
* name
* description
* price
* menu_id
```

I want to display all `menu_categories` that have `dishes`, if a category doesn't have a dish it will not be selected.

I know I need to use JOIN in some manner, but I can't figure out how. Everything I have tried have returned an empty field set.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.id, m.name, m.description 
FROM  menu_categories m 
JOIN dishes d 
ON d.menu_id = m .id
```

Comment: This only displays the first category, even if the first category has no dishes

Comment: perhaps you could add some sample data to you question?

Comment: No it doesn't.  It displays all lists of menu_categories that have a dishes relationship.  Because there is no WHERE predicate, all menu_categories with dishes lists will be returned in the resultset.

Comment: OK, your SQL was perfect... it was my mistake, played around with it... added the required WHERE clause and it works perfectly! Thank you